# Uncaught Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.props.navigation.navigate') touchableHandlePress@[native code]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am creating a component called `HomeIcon` and inserting it in my `header` via `defaultNavigationOptions` > `headerRight`, I added an `onPress` in this component by assigning `this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');` with the purpose that clicking on this component loads the `MainScreen` but when I click the error described in the above heading occurs.
Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
      }}>
        <Image style={styles.buttonHome} source={require('../icons/home2.png')} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonHome: {
    aspectRatio: 1,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.08,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.08,
    margin: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.018
    }
});
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Main from './source/screens/MainScreen';
import CustomCards from './source/screens/CustomCardsScreen';
import HomeIcon from './source/components/HomeIcon';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
  'Main': {
    screen: Main,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Tela Principal'
    }
  },
  'CustomCards': {
    screen: CustomCards,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Cartões Personalizados'
    }
  }
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTitleStyle: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    headerLeft: (null),
    headerRight: (
      <HomeIcon />
    ),
    headerStyle:{
      backgroundColor: '#7d253b'
    },
    headerTintColor: '#FFF'
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.13",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.43",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Visit the project repository in GitHub for more details: https://github.com/Alex-Xavier/ACTIFICA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defaultNavigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitleStyle: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    headerLeft: (null),
    headerRight: (
       <HomeIcon navigation={navigation} />
       ),
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#7d253b',
    },
      headerTintColor: '#FFF',
   });
```

Comment: Friend, the resolution is this same but the syntax is a bit different from the correct one, follows the final resolution ( if you can edit ):

Comment: `}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitleStyle: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        textAlignVertical: 'center'
      },
      /*headerLeft: (<View></View>),*/
      headerRight: (
        <HomeIcon navigation={navigation} />
      ),
      headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: '#7d253b'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#FFF'
    }
  }
});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a navigation object to that component. 
'this.props.navigation' only available in a screens that is directly assign to stack/tab/drawer navigation.
In your case it's screens 'Main' and 'CustomCards'

HomeIcon component have no idea what is a this.props.navigation.

You have to pass 'navigation' as a props. Like so:

```
 headerRight: ({ navigation }) => <HomeIcon  navigation={navigation}/>
```

Then in you HomeIcon it's will be available as this.props.navigation.

Comment: I added the suggested line of code in the `headerRight` property this way
`defaultNavigationOptions: {
     headerTitleStyle: {
       flexGrow: 1,
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       textAlign: 'center'
     },
     headerLeft: (null),
     headerRight: ({navigation}) => <HomeIcon navigation = {navigation} />,
     headerStyle: {
       backgroundColor: '# 7d253b'
     },
     headerTintColor: '#FFF'
   }
}); `
After testing the HomeIcon disappears from the screen or it is not rendered.

Comment: check styles for HomeIcon. Try to remove flex property if you have one.

Comment: There is no flex property. I added the style code and package.json the question.

Comment: try import HomeIcon with  braces, like so : 
import { HomeIcon }  from './source/components/HomeIcon';

Comment: Still unsuccessful!